# How to install php56 on CentOS 6 x86_64

Tags: php, centos6

When I run `yum install php php-devel php-mysql php-gd php-mbstring`, it will install php5.3.

```
yum list installed *php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.kddilabs.jp
 * extras: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * updates: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
Installed Packages
php.x86_64                       5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-cli.x86_64                   5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-common.x86_64                5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-devel.x86_64                 5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-gd.x86_64                    5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-mbstring.x86_64              5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-mysql.x86_64                 5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
php-pdo.x86_64                   5.3.3-46.el6_6               @updates
```

I just removed it `yum remove php php-cli php-common php-devel php-gd php-mbstring php-mysql php-pdo`.

And I tried `yum install php56w php56w-devel php56w-mysql php56w-gd php56w-mbstring`, but they are not available.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.kddilabs.jp
 * extras: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
 * updates: ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp
No package php56w available.
No package php56w-devel available.
No package php56w-mysql available.
No package php56w-gd available.
No package php56w-mbstring available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I install php5.6 on CentOS 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would add repo into centos 6 by:

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Next,

```
#yum clean all
#yum install php56w php56w-common
```

I hope help you!

Answer (score 6):

CentOS now offers [Software Collections (SCL)](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) as a repo installable from base:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

Once you've installed the SCL repo, you can install php 5.6:

```
yum install rh-php56
```

The [CentOS documentation](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) is slightly dated as is the [Red Hat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html-single/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html), but newer versions of php, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, MySQL, perl, ruby, etc. are available.  It's also available on CentOS and RHEL 7 and is theoretically better integrated with the OS.  The notes say that adding packages through SCL won't interfere with the system's utilities, such as yum.

To make the SCL version of PHP the default on the command line, run the following as root to add to the default profile:

```
printf '#!/bin/bash\nsource scl_source enable rh-php56\n' > /etc/profile.d/php56.sh
chmod ugo+r /etc/profile.d/php56.sh
```

This makes using pear to add PHP packages easier by setting `$PATH` to include `/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/...`

Comment: are those safe and new? Centos repos always very old.

Comment: It's the official CentOS SCL repo for CentOS, so I'd say it's as safe as the rest of CentOS.  It's certainly safer than some other repositories because it won't interfere with of the other CentOS update repos or system packages.  If you're using something that's not CentOS, these instructions aren't for you.

Comment: centos-release-scl is [`x86_64 only`](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [REMI's repository](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/)

To enable it, follow these steps:

1. `yum install http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm`
2. edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and, under then `[remi-php56]` tag, set `enabled=1`
3. `yum install php`

Please note that, doing that, you will update the system-wide php package to the 5.6 version. If you need, for some reason, install PHP 5.6 alongside the older, CentOS-distributed relase, you had to do a more complex side-by-side installation.

Comment: Instead of 2, simply use:  yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56

Answer (score -1):

Try installing from specific repo

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi-php56" install php
```