# CentOS installing MySQL 5.6.26

Tags: mysql, centos6

My server is CentOS 6.7 x86_64. I installed mysql by `yum -y install mysql-server`. But this install v5.1.73.

```
Installed:
  mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.73-5.el6_6

Dependency Installed:
  mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-5.el6_6  perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6
  perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.609-4.el6
```

How can I install the latest version v5.6.26 as of today.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the CentOS repositories, add the repository of Oracle. Detailed information can be found in this link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-rpm.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I do it:

```
yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-3/percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm
yum install Percona-Server-client-56 Percona-Server-server-56
```

This yields 5.6.x

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26-74.0, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
```

Note that Percona is a highly performant fork of MySQL. It is a drop-in replacement, so everything works just like normal, standard MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

that is what is in the repository of CentOS, if you want to get the latest version you have to self-compile it from source or use 3rd party repositories. It is not a rocket science!!!!

Comment: I wouldn't recommand compiling when rpm packages are available on the editor website.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS and Red Hat now have a repository called "Software Collections".  You can install MySQL 5.6 by following [the instructions here](https://serverfault.com/a/775948/267333) and substituting `rh-mysql56` in the second command.