# Package rh-php56 not available on CentOS 6 via centos-release-scl

Tags: centos6, php56, scl

Installing package [rh-php56](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php56/) in a CentOS 6 Docker image *used* to work using [the methodology described here](https://serverfault.com/a/775948/283225), but now I get the following error from `yum`:

> No package rh-php56 available.

Querying `yum`, I see that other packages from Software Collections (e.g., rh-php70) *are* available, so I know that `centos-release-scl` is working.

The rh-php56 RPMs exist in every mirror I've checked, e.g., http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/sclo/x86_64/rh/rh-php56/

My workaround has been to install the packages by referencing the full mirror URLs to the RPMs, which feels silly.

The summary on the SCL page does note that:

> This collection is EOL since April 2018.

I am working on a PHP7 upgrade, but need to do some work with 5.6 in the interim. Are EOL'ed SCL packages somehow excluded from `yum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [RHSCL life cyle documentation](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl/)

rh-php56 have reached its end of life in April 2018, so will removed soon from live repository.

It will stay available on vault (like php54 and php55), but I heartily recommend to switch to a maintained version (rh-php70 or rh-php71)

BTW, it still online for now:

```
# LANG=C yum list rh-php56\*
Installed Packages
rh-php56.x86_64                2.3-1.el6           @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-cli.x86_64        5.6.25-1.el6        @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-common.x86_64     5.6.25-1.el6        @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-pear.noarch       1:1.9.5-4.el6       @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 1.3.6-3.el6         @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-process.x86_64    5.6.25-1.el6        @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-php-xml.x86_64        5.6.25-1.el6        @centos-sclo-rh   
rh-php56-runtime.x86_64        2.3-1.el6           @centos-sclo-rh   
Available Packages
rh-php56-build.x86_64          2.0-6.el6           rhscl-rh-php56-el6
...
```